# In the sentence "Go help yourself", is 'yourself' both the direct object and the subject?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjects, direct-objects

In the sentence "Go help yourself", is 'yourself' both the direct object and the subject?

Can a subject and direct object be the exact same word in a sentence? If not, what is 'yourself' here?

Comment: 'yourself' is the object. You could easily replace it with any other object, without it becoming the subject.

Comment: If you're new at the English language (which you say you are), why are you asking about obscenities? You could just as easily have used the inoffensive "Go try yourself", or similar.

Comment: @BillJ Fully agree with the sentiment, but "[Go and ] Do it yourself" would be a more useful example

Comment: It's funny isn't it? We get users deleting the terms "coloured girls", "gay" and "Down syndrome" because someone is or might be offended, yet whenever someone uses obscene language, gratuitously, we leave it be for fear of being called snobs or prigs. I am offended by the question, does that count? -1

Comment: @Mari-LouA Quite so, I initially put "do it", and then for some stupid reason changed it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For those not following, the original question used obscene language which was not necessary for the grammatical question. It was replaced with a grammatically similar but non-obscene word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original version of the Q. included inappropriate & offensive language - and therefore appears to be a 'spam' Q. that not not merit any serious consideration.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost right.

This sentence is simply an imperative clause.

As in: Go help your sister or Please help your sister.

The subject in these sentences is **you**-but when we actually say the you, the sentence is more commanding/ emphasized, as in you go help your sister, etc.

the pronoun yourself is a reflexive pronoun and we use it when the subject and the object of the clause are the same, so in a way you are right, though a in your sentence *you* is the subject

Answer (score 1):

(Someone else answered while I was writing this, but it gives more complete information.)

"Yourself" is a [reflexive pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun) functioning as a direct object, used here with an imperative verb. The British Council's [Learn English says](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/reflexive-pronouns) "We use a reflexive pronoun: as a direct object when the object is the same as the subject of the verb". "Yourself" refers to the subject and object, but grammatically it's the object.

The verb is an [imperative form](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-and-imperatives/imperative-clauses-be-quiet), which doesn't take a subject (hence no subject here), but it's more complex than a usual imperative, which can be one word (e.g. "Die!") or verb plus object ("Hit him!"). "Go X" where X is also a verb is a colloquial equivalent to "go and X" ([see under "go and" here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/go)) - hence "go fuck yourself" equals "go and fuck yourself"; Macmillan dictionaries gives "go and do something"="used for telling someone to do something, especially when you are annoyed".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, "yourself" is both the subject and the direct object of the verb. This is the usual case with [reflexive](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/many-cases-pronouns-subject-object-possessive-reflexive/) constructions. "Please, sit yourself down, and make yourself comfortable" is another example of a reflexive construction, though perhaps not heard as frequently as the one you gave.

Comment: The question is about the grammatical slots of subject and object, not the referents. The subject is missing (it is imperative, yielding an implied 2nd person) and the object 'yourself' is the reflexive word. These are distinct things. Of course, they refer to the same individual (the 2nd person), but since subject and object are mentioned, that's not what is being asked.